# how to substract only working days from a specific date?

Tags: vba, excel

assuming that we have a date of 18/06/2015 for example, and we want to substruct 5 days from it, (Saturday and Sunday not included).

I have thought to elaborate an algorihm with `DateAdd()`but i wanna know wether there is a function that that enables to do so

thanks in advance

Comment: If you're using Office 2010 or higher, check out [WorksheetFunction.WorkDay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196438.aspx).

Comment: @Comintern yes I use Office 2013

Comment: no Just Office 2013 :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `workday` worksheet function:

```
WorksheetFunction.WorkDay("2015-06-18",-5)
```

Comment: I tried to use this function but it has that run-time error: 1004 error ("impossible to learn WorkDay property of the WorksheetFunction class")

Comment: Are you sure you are using correct syntax? This works for me. [See a similar problem here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10635048/excel-error-1004-unable-to-get-property-of-worksheetfunction-class-appear)

Comment: Try using it with constant values, as seen in my answer, to see if it works at all.

Comment: @Benss the error you have is usually caused by improper date format in the cell which the function is referencing to.

Comment: if the user uses this file with Office 2006, this function it will work ? or it's work just for Office 2010 and higher ?

Comment: Yes, this function works with previous versions of Excel, from 2003 and on (maybe even before, I'm not sure).

Answer (score 0):

=WORKDAY(A1,5)

Assuming you have whatever original date in cell A1.

Comment: Since Bens wants to subtract 5 days that would be `=WORKDAY(A1,-5)` which yields the date 11/06/2015

Comment: @Clif but me I used the French format dd/mm/yyyy !! how I should do ?

Comment: My apologies, I had noticed the different format, but had assumed that workday would work with whatever date format the computer's system used. I do have a question, when you put 18/06/2015 in a cell and press `Ctrl`+1 is the number sample 42173?

Comment: The date format doesn't matter, as long as Excel recognises it as a date.

Comment: Remember: inside a formula (if you are using date constants), or in VBA, always use the ISO standard formatting. That is: yyyy-mm-dd. This will always be recognised, and will work on every machine, regardless to its locational settings.

Comment: Does this function not exist in excel VBA? Office 365.

Answer (score 0):

It worked:

```
Fecha_Inicio = (Extr_DiaAp & " - " & Extr_MesAp & " - " & Extr_YearAp)
```

'the last was just a Date that i extracted from other cells.
Fecha_Comp = WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Fecha_Inicio, 25)
'Fecha_Comp is a Date that starts from Fecha_Inicio 25 working days ahead.

```
MsgBox Fecha_Comp
```