# Using worksheet function countif for filtered cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the code below to loop through a filtered column and collect each name of sales person as it loops through; I am using the SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) which is picking up the only the visible rows. I only want the name once so I am using the countif worksheet function. Once I have the name I am storing it in a temp variable (namelist_tmp) and adding a semicolon. The end game is to create a variable (namelist) with each name separated by a semicolon so I can use it in the .to section of some email code I have.

I am able to loop through and capture the name but when I am trying to assign the temp variable to the final variable I get a Run-time error 5 Invalid Procedure call or argument at the namelist_tmp code:
`namelist = Left(namelist_tmp, Len(namelist_tmp) - 2)`

I an not sure if I am going about this the right way, can a kind soul help my see the error of my ways?

```
Sub filteredstuff()
Dim lastRow As Long, myrange As Range
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
For Each myrange In Range("E11:E" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
'At each name, use COUNTIF to look upwards and see if the name already exists.
'If not, add name, semi-colon and space to temporary name list
         If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("E11:E" & myrange.Row), _
         Range("E" & myrange.Row)) < 2 Then
             namelist_tmp = namelist_tmp & Range("E" & myrange.Row).Value & "; "
         End If
'Strip last semi-colon & space off of temp list
             namelist = Left(namelist_tmp, Len(namelist_tmp) - 2)
Next myrange
MsgBox namelist
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run your code on dummy data and for me it works, I don't get any error.
And this line is perfect, it should be okay:

```
namelist = Left(namelist_tmp, Len(namelist_tmp) - 2)
```

Can you give some more details?

Comment: Ok So after some testing I realized that the code works perfectly when the data is not filtered, in other words I am showing all the data. Once I filter it and the row numbers are no longer consecutive I get the Run-time error 5 Invalid Procedure call or argument at the namelist_tmp code: namelist = Left(namelist_tmp, Len(namelist_tmp) - 2)

Comment: After doing a lot of research I have come to find out that WorksheetFunction.CountIf does not work with filtered data. At this point I don't know what to try.

Comment: After reading your comment I checked your code for filtered data, for me it works perfectly even for filtered data. Maybe you are using an older version of Excel? This is really strange.
By the way, is it a requirement for you to start the range in E column from Row 11? I am referring to this part:
`WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("E11:E" & myrange.Row)`

For your situation, maybe this could be a possible solution:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37406231/excel-issue-with-countif-with-visible-cells-only)
Hope it helps.